# How to import email contacts the same way as twitter is doing?

Tags: c#, twitter

Is there a standard way to let the website user import his email contacts in an asp.net MVC website?

Twitter use a secure way to let the user import his contacts, which is letting the user put his username and password inside the email service not in twitter.

Such as opening a popup for gmail to login there then return back to twitter with the contacts.

I used some libraries which import the contacts but with asking the user to put his username and password in the website then it get the contacts, which will is not secure from the user point of view.

So my question is: is there a ready solution for importing contacts from gmail, aol, yahoo the same way as twitter is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of products you listed support [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID). It is secured way how to get user's digital identity.

To get emails, you need use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) to get authorized access to protected items (emails)

Comment: how to do that? do you have examples or links?

Comment: Each of these companies have specialized webs for developers (for example http://developer.yahoo.com/openid/, http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html), with examples etc.

Comment: and these will be the same as twitter is doing it?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543676/linkedin-twitter-facebook-as-oauth-and-openid-use

Answer (score 1):

Try this library

http://contactgrabber.stescodes.com/

it uses openauth basically.